# surf object array in JSON in react javascript that retrieve from axios API

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing, axios

I call Axios for example API in react, I want to render just specific field in my array for example just first person company name in output. 
e.g "person[0].cpmpany.name" I expect to have ""Romaguera-Crona" but I got error.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
    }
  },...]
```

My react component is :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
    state = {
        persons: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
            .then(res => {
                const persons = res.data;
                // const persons2 = JSON.parse(persons);
                this.setState({ persons : persons});
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.phone}</li>)}
                { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.address.street}</li>)}
              // { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person[0].cpmpany.name}</li>)} // here is the issue

            })
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to render specific component from JSON file or loop on Specific cell in may JSON object. for example for-loop that just render person.cpmpany.name

Comment: In the code where are you using `persons[0]`. This part is unclear.

Comment: is `{person.phone}` working correctly? please try `{person.company.name}` please see the typo for `cpmpany` in `{person[0].cpmpany.name}`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in `{person[0].cpmpany.name}`. Also, since you are already mapping on `this.state.persons` array, you can simply use `{person.company.name}`.

Please try and replacing `{person[0].cpmpany.name}` with `{person.company.name}`

Comment: thanks for answer but I want to render just first Jason object in array. person[0] this {person.company.name} show all names but I want first or second person name.

Comment: then just don't loop over your state and use `{this.state.persons[0].company.name}` directly. If this is not you want please edit the question and share your use case in detail possibly with examples.